# Ralink RT5370 USB WiFi

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, ralink

I am a relative Linux newbie and have installed Lubuntu 18.04 on a relatively old laptop. Generally works well, but neither internal WiFi (Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG) nor the more recently purchased USB WiFi dongle (Ralink RT5370 Wireless Adapter) work.
The system (via 'lspci' & 'lsusb') sees them both.
I am currently using Ethernet, but would like to get the Ralink RT5370 working.  The laptop has a WiFi on/off switch, but doesn't matter whether this is on or off, in Networking it still says'WiFi is disabled by hardware switch'.
I have looked at previous similar queries and answers. There seem to be a variety of potential solutions, all of them leading nowhere. Does anyone have a simple, reliable solution?

Comment: Can you remove the internal wifi card?

Comment: Hi Jeremy31. Yes - internal wifi card is removable.

Comment: Removing it could clear the hard block

Comment: Brilliant! Simple and effective. I removed the wireless PCI card & rebooted. Mousepad stopped working, but cured by reboot in recovery mode.
Ralink USB WiFi adapter is now working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your wifi is software blocked. You can check that by typing this in terminal:

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

If it says *soft blocked: yes*, you can unblock it with the command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock <device name>
```

Comment: Thank you temzky, for your prompt reply.  I tried that, and it returned:

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

So that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant! Simple and effective. I removed the wireless PCI card & rebooted. Mousepad stopped working, but cured by reboot in recovery mode.
Ralink USB WiFi adapter is now working. Many thanks!